# Remove duplicated items in Arc attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have imported a set of points into ARCmap using a kml file created in google earth. During this process, a number of the points were duplicated (see below). Is there a way to get rid of the duplicated points in arc rather than recreating the kml file which will be hugely time consuming?

[image: Duplicate items]

Comment: Note that the Identical tools given in both current answers require an Advanced license.

Comment: If you don't have an Advanced license, you can play around with the Summarize tool to find duplicates.  It does require some scripting or manual work to remove them however.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Delete Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool. In the syntax you specify the field you want to look for duplicates in and ArcMap deletes all but one of them automatically. You can also use the [Find Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000) tool to just find the identical features and delete them manually if you would like to check the results yourself.

Answer (score 8):

There is a tool called [Find Identical (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000) that does exactly what you are after.  The tool adds a new field to the output feature class indicating the status.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this python script at field calculator to find identical itens and then delete them. Create first a field (e.g 'duplicate') of short type. Then using field calculator use the python script bellow:

```
d = []
def isDuplicate(t):
    import string
    global d
    iD = 0
    for item in d:
        if item == t:
            iD = 1
            continue
    if iD == 1:
        return 1
    elif iD == 0:
        d.append(t)
        return 0
```

Also select 'codeblock' and use the code bellow replacing !YourField! for the field you just created (e.g. 'duplicated').

`isDuplicate( !YourField!)`

After running the above script the field created will have *1* for duplicated fields and *0* otherwise.

Comment: Simpler Python script code for field Calculator can be found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183472/identifying-duplicate-attributes-using-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make the  VB Script that was provided above work (don't see it now)  I did however have success  with the python script above using the field calculator. I'm using ArcGIS10.3

1. Add new field (type short) I named it dup.
2. Use field calculator on the new dup column.    Selected Python
       radio button and Show Codeblock check box in the field calculator.
3. Pasted the above python script in the Pre-Logic Script Code: window.
4. In the second isDuplicate window replace the isDuplicate(
       !YourField!) with the field you are checking for duplicates on.In
   my case it was wells. isDuplicate( !wells!).

Thanks!